# Bookmarking Script?

Tags: php, mysql, bookmarks, favorites

It's for a user to "save" a story he's read. I got a snippet of code from SO a few days ago but, I can't seem to get it to work. I want to snatch the url from the page a user is currently viewing, insert the url in a MySQL DB and output the url back to client under a favorite section on the website. Any ideas?

When I try the code below, I get a T String error.

```
  Index.php
  <?php     
  function curPageURL() {      
   $pageURL = 'http';  
      if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}  $pageURL .= "://";  
      if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {   $pageURL .= $_SERVER ["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 

  } else {   $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI";
  }  
  return $pageURL;
  } 

 ?> 

    <html> 
    <body> 
    <form action="storeBookmark.php?url=<?php echo curPageURL();" method="GET"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form> 
    </body> 
    </html> 

   <?php    
   $url = $_GET['url'];     

   $dbc = mysqli_connect('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx')    
   or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');     

  $query = "INSERT INTO xxxx (url)".    "VALUES('$url')";     

 $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)   or die('Error.');  

 mysqli_close($dbc);  
 ?>
```

Comment: What T_STRING error? What line?

Comment: form action="storeboookphp......

Comment: line 17...i keep receiving a t string error at that line

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form action="storeBookmark.php?url=<?php echo curPageURL();?>" method="GET"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Added in closing php tag for curPageURL() function call.

You should also not store unsanitized user data in your database. Since you're using mysqli you should use a [prepared statement](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');

$url = $_GET['url'];

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'INSERT INTO table1 (url) VALUES(?)')) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $url);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```